# navbar width exceeds viewport of webpage

Tags: html, css, navbar

hello guys i want to display html content in with margin on the sides with 50px &50px .
here is the problem my nav bar witdh is et to 100% then it elongates to right end but correctly positioned on left
i have given the image below:[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmtZ5.png)

i show the html& css

css:

```
<style>
            .top{
                width:100%;
                height:300px;
                color:#ccc;
                font-size: 40px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: forestgreen;
            }
            .align{
                height:100%;
                margin-left: 50px;
                margin-right: 50px;
                background-color: darkgray;
            }
            ul{
                position: absolute;
                width:100%;
                list-style-type: none;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: black;
                color: azure;
                float:left;
                padding: 0;
            }
            nav{
                position: inherit;
            }
            li{
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 14px 16px;

                display: block;
                float: left;
                margin: none;
                text-align: center;
            }
            li.active{
                background-color: darkred;
            }
            .navbar-fixed {
                  top: 0;
                  z-index: 100;
                  position: fixed;
                  width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
```

HTML:

```
<body class="bg-danger">
        <div class="align bg-success" >
            <div id=image-header class=top>
        NO:1 Hosting Site 
            </div>
        <nav   >
            <ul>
                <a href="index.php"><li class="active">
                    Home

                </li></a>

                <a href="login.php"><li>
                    Login
                </li></a>

                <a href="registration.php"><li>
                    Register
                    </li></a>

                <a href="account.php"><li >           
                    Profile
                </li></a>
            </ul>
            </nav>

            </div>
    </body>
```

i want it to fix it like this (i used 92.5% in width)with 100% width   [this is just model like affix in bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd4nI.png)
and want to know why it cant be fixed with 100% in div element
image

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. It's clear that it's about HTML/CSS from the tags you added, and it's clear you need help or you wouldn't be posting here. Removing that information leaves your title pretty useless. Your title should describe the problem or question in a clear enough way to be of use to future readers here who see it in a list of search results. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite i have updated question :) late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `width: calc(100% - 100px);` on that navbar to get the correct width.

Comment: what does 100px means here

Comment: for the margins: 50px + 50px = 100px. So the width will be 100% of the viewport minus the sum of the left and right margins .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Just try it, and you'll see.